# React can't find my module even if the pathing seems correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I'm currently learning React and I'm having a problem, when I launch my app it says that it can't find modules at the location I gave. I believe I have written the correct path but it would seem that's not the case. I've looked around and tried all the different options I've found but they haven't worked so far.
Is there something I'm not getting?

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

[image: This is the organization of my files and folders]

[image: This is the code I have in my Home.jsx file]

I tried changing the way I wrote the path to find the files and elements I need but to no avail.

- `./`
- `../`
- `src/components/`

I always get the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See whenever you want to import some component from different file, following thing you need to keep in mind.

1. if the file is present in same folder, you can simply do
   "./file" where "./" represents that, file is going to be picked from
   same location.
2. if the file is present one level outside current folder.
   "../file" where "../" represent we are going a level outside the
   current folder, keep in mind **their is no space present between dots or the
   slash** "../".
3. if you have to access some component from file from inside folder of current
   location, we simply have to give folder name example, "./FolderLevel1/file".

   Taking your case we will be using "../../components/banner/Banner" since we
   have to go two level up and then have to import some component.

**Just remember there has to be no space between path dots or slashes.**

Answer (score 0):

Import it like this.

```
import Banner from "../../components/banner/Banner"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HomePage` is file `/src/pages/home/Home.jsx` and the imports will be ***relative*** to this location unless you've setup up absolute paths. For example, to import a component from the `/src/components` directory you'll first need to "move" back/up ***two*** path segments, e.g. `"../.."` to `/src`, and then into the components directory, e.g. `"../../components"`. To import the `Banner` component, use `import Banner from '../../components/banner/Banner';`. To import the `Card` component use `import Card from '../../components/card/Card';`. And so on.

```
import './home.scss';
import Banner from '../../components/banner/Banner';
import Card from '../../components/card/Card';
import imgBannerHome from '../../assets/banner-falaise.png';
import logement from '../../data/logements.json';

export function HomePage() {
  ...
}
```

If you wish to avoid needing to use ***relative*** import paths everywhere you can configure your project to use ***absolute*** paths. Create a `jsconfig.json` file in the root project directory with the following entries:

`/jsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

VS Code should automatically import this config and allow using absolute imports from the `src` directory.

Example:

```
import './home.scss';
import Banner from 'components/banner/Banner';
import Card from 'components/card/Card';
import imgBannerHome from 'assets/banner-falaise.png';
import logement from 'data/logements.json';

export function HomePage() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Holly molly thank you so much ! This is great  !